# How to simplify the product of $(x^{2^k}+x^{-2^k})$ over $k$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, products

> Simplify $$\left(x+\frac1x\right)\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)\left(x^4+\frac1{x^4}\right)\ldots\left(x^{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{x^{2^{n-1}}}\right)$$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Should I be using mathematical induction on $n$ for this, or is there another way?

Comment: I don't see any statement to be proved.

Comment: @bububu: I guessed that the question is really to simplify the expression; if that’s not correct, please tell us what the question is supposed to be. Also, the exponents don’t make sense: if they’re powers of $2$, then you can’t get $2n-1$. Was that supposed to be $$x^{2^{n-1}}=\frac1{x^{2^{n-1}}}\;?$$

Comment: @bububu You need to explain the powers a bit, as the sequence $1, 2, 4, \dots 2n-1$ does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

> am I gonna solve it by using mathematical induction or..

I don't know how you're going to solve it, or what comes after the ellipsis.  But let me tell you, I multiplied that thing by $\displaystyle \left( x - \frac{1}{x}\right)$ and the *craziest* thing happened...

Comment: While this is one of my favorite tricks, it's just that: a trick. The solution to this problem can actually be *discovered* (not merely *verified*) in a relatively straightforward fashion without having to resort to magic.

Comment: I do not often use magic in mathematics, but if I do then it always gives me a great feeling.

Comment: @Hurkyl Discovery is a form of trickery.

Answer (score 1):

You will *eventually* use mathematical induction in your solution.

However, you have some work to do before you get to that point: the first thing you need to do before you can solve this problem is to figure out what's going on.

One of the usual approaches to solving problems where you don't know what's going on is to look at special cases. This is especially true in problems where you have something going on "$n$ times" or the like.

Before trying to tackle the general problem, you first tackle the $n=1$ case in isolation. Then you look at the $n=2$ case. Then the $n=3$ case, and maybe a few more.

Frequently, after working through these special cases, the it becomes clear how th general case is going to look. At that point, you write down what you think the answer is going to be, and then use some means (e.g. induction, as you thought) to verify that your answer is correct.